# Auto-Numbering depending upon Row or Column being hidden

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

*I want the cell to number itself in an incremental order depending upon the filters. I found the easiest way is to check for the above Row if it is hidden or not then number itself from 1 if hidden and previous cell value+1 if not hidden.

I've tried to achieve this using the Formula*

```
=IF(COUNTA(ADDR)>SUBTOTAL(103, ADDR), 1, ADDR+1)
```

*Where* `ADDR` *is defined as follows:*

```
=ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN(), 4, TRUE)
```

`SUBTOTAL` *function returns* `#VALUE` *as it cannot contain 3-D References.

Tried replacing* `SUBTOTAL()` *function with* `AGGREGATE()`, *same issue.*

*Tried to use* `VALUE()` *function to convert the* `ADDR` *string to value.*

*I tried to use* **VBA**

```
Public Function IsHid(i As Integer)

    Dim re As Range, x As Integer
    Set re = Range("A" & i)
    If re.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        Set re = Range("A" & i + 1)
        re = 1
    Else
        x = re.Value + 1
        Set re = Range("A" & i + 1)
        re = x
    End If

End Function
```

*The above function returns* `#VALUE`.
*The below function also returns* `#VALUE`.

```
Public Function IsHid(i As Integer)

    If Excel.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Hidden Then
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 1
    Else
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + 1
    End If

End Function
```

***Very much appreciated if this functionality can be obtained by means of*** **`FORMULAS`** ***rather than the*** **`VBA`**

Comment: Do I understand correctly if you just want 1, 2, 3 etc. only on the visible rows and that these numbers stay the same even if the filter changes? E.g. if rows 2 and 4 are visible, they'd be numbered 1 and 2. If rows 3 and 5 are visible and 2 and 4 invisible, then rows 3 and 5 should be numbered 1 and 2?

Comment: @RikSportel Yes, that is what I am looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Subtotal combined with Count(A):

`=SUBTOTAL(3,B$2:B2)` and paste down.

This can be in column A and will number only visible rows when you filter on B, C, etc.

You might want to take a look [here](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/03/19/number-the-visible-rows-in-excel-autofilter/) as well, for additional explanation.

**Edit:**
Let's say you have Sheet1 and you fill up Range A:G. In column A you want the numbering described in the question. Then Range A1 will hold a header (e.g. FilteredID) and Range B:G will hold your other values.

In range A2 all the way down, you put the formula `=Subtotal(3, B$2:B2)`, in Range A3 this will be `=Subtotal(3, B$2:B3)`, in A4 `=Subtotal(3, B$2:B4)`, etc.
Now, when you filter on column B, C, D etc. so you'll have invisible rows, the numbering in column A will show the visible Row number.

Comment: Sorry to ask you again but I am having hard hard time using that either, could you please simplify a bit more...

Comment: See edit. I can't make it simpler than it is. Just put that formula in a column, filter on another one, and you'll see that the rownumber that the formula outputs is equal to the visible row. (e.g. row 2 and 4 are filtered, then row 3 will hold the value "1" and row 5 will hold the value "2".)

Comment: Cheers, you're welcome. Accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Nice approach (+1)

Answer (score 0):

For example, assuming you want to start numbering in row 2 and in column A and you have Excel 2010 or later:

```
=AGGREGATE(4,5,A$1:A1)+1
```

Just adjust the start cell as required.